# How to export ES6 module and import it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a file like this :

```
let Utils = {
  //random stuff code
}

module.exports = Utils
```

I wanna run `import Utils form 'Utils'` anywhere, what I should do?

Comment: I removed a lot of the tags you used since your question doesn't mention any of them. If your question is specific to one or more of the tags I removed, feel free to add details into your question about it and add the relevant tags.

Comment: Thanks, I just a Rookie...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
let Utils = {
  //random stuff code
}

export default Utils
```

Then:

```
import Utils from '/path/to/utils';
```